# Difference between Braces and Quotes in Variables

Tags: javascript, arrays, angularjs, variables, curly-braces

I am trying to add an initial empty value for a variable and I dont understand the different between these:

```
var question = '';

var question = {};
```

What is the difference between using Braces and Quotes when defining an empty value for a variable?

Comment: [MDN Learn Javascript](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/learn/javascript) <-- Start here if you don't know basic JavaScript syntax.

Comment: @dfsq I know it is hard not knowing the basics. But I need to start somewhere when learning.

Comment: Of course but advanced frameworks can only confuse you if you don't know basics. Above link would help you to start. Good luck!

Comment: Thanks... I am struggling since I am learning both Angular as well as Javascript at the same time. So I need to go back to javascript tutorial to understand why a syntax is like this in Angular. Sometimes basic questions like these haunts me and confuses me. Thanks @cookie monster for the link. I am having a read through it now.

Comment: Why was this question downvoted? A beginner question is still a question.

Comment: @RowanFreeman: Hover your mouse over the down arrow, and you'll see *"This question does not show any research effort;"*. Basic research would answer this question. It's generally expected of askers that they have first done their own research before asking. There's no shortage of basic JavaScript books and tutorials, any one of which would have explained the fundamental syntax.

Comment: @cookiemonster Before I asked this question, I thought a variable was an object. That got me confused on why there is a difference in syntax. When I read the object is a collection of properties, it didnt make much sense to me. But your example in your answer below is what made clear sense to me. I did google this before but it just got me confused. Thats why I asked here... I know I should have mentioned this in my question.

Comment: Yeah, it's a good idea to describe what you've tried, or in this case what specifically is the source of your confusion based on you've learned already. Otherwise it looks like you're just trying to be spoon-fed information instead of taking efforts for yourself.

Comment: Funny that 3 people upvote the comment from @RowanFreeman that whines about downvotes, and no one upvotes a comment that points to helpful learning resources. Gives insight into the mentality of the folks here. *(blackops_programmer showed his appreciation for the link. I'm talking about others)*.

Comment: Maybe the difference between an object and a string comes easy to you, @cookiemonster, but it may not to everyone. A lot of questions (perhaps most) on Stack Overflow could be classified as unnecessary if the questioner put in sufficient research. Some might need 5 minutes, others might require many hours. There are many 'simple' questions about pointers too, but that's because it's a difficult concept to grasp. Tutorials and guides might talk about objects and strings, but to someone new to programming it's a fair question.

Comment: @RowanFreeman: It has nothing to do with coming easy. Not all things in life must be easy. I remember very clearly starting out, and I remember very clearly researching every question I had for hours or days. But this isn't difficult to grasp. If you think the OP can't grasp it, then you must hold a very low opinion of him. What I presented in the answer below is no different that that which would be presented in nearly any arbitrarily chosen beginners tutorial. What you so clearly fail to grasp, is that it isn't for my benefit or the benefit of SO that people research, but it's for their own.

Comment: *"If you think the OP can't grasp it, then you must hold a very low opinion of him"* Don't put words in my mouth. *"What you so clearly fail to grasp [...]"* I don't know why you're hostile. In many languages a string behaves **like** an object or **is** an object. Making the distinction between the two (as a tutorial would) mightn't clear everything up, and sometimes no amount of research will help. Either way, your answer cleared up everything perfectly. I'm not saying it's a **great** question. I just don't think it deserved to be down-voted.

Comment: *"...and sometimes no amount of research will help"* WRT this question, that would be quite the stretch. I have utter confidence in *blackops_programmer*'s ability to find and comprehend answers to questions about basic syntax on his own.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`''` is a [string](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-4.3.16).
`{}` is an [object](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-4.3.3).

Both of these are examples of *literal* syntax. This means that you can define a type of data with its value initialized. This is the most common approach to defining data in JavaScript.

---

The first creates a `string` type with no characters. The quotation marks are merely part of the syntax that denotes the opening and closing of the string. They are not part of the resulting data.

A string is immutable, so it's impossible to add characters to the string you created, though you can replace it with a new string held by that variable.

An example of a string initialized with characters would be:

```
var question = "Who is John Galt?";
```

The resulting string contains the characters between the quotation marks. Again, the quotation marks are not part of the result. They merely denote the literal syntax used to create the string.

---

The second creates an `object` type that contains no members. Again, the curly braces simply denote the start and end of the literal syntax. They have nothing to do with the actual data contained in the object.

An object can be mutated *(except in certain situations that aren't relevant right now)*. So you can update the members of this object by adding properties in a variety of ways.

An example of an object initialized with members would be:

```
var question = {
    firstName: "John",
    lastName: "Galt"
};
```

The resulting object owns two members and inherits a few more. The members are key/value pairs, where the key is ultimately represented as a string *(though here we used property identifier syntax, which represents a subset of valid keys)*, and where the value can be any JavaScript data type *(in this example, I used string literal syntax to define string values)*.

Comment: Excellent Answer! Your answer made so much sense! Thank you so much for the detailed response. Its the best example and definition I've seen so far. :)

Answer (score 0):

When you say initial empty you need to know the type.
Although javascript is loosely coupled you should understand the basic types.

```
var a; <- undefined no type
var a = {} <- defined object "empty" of defined members
var a = [] <- defined array "empty" of defined elements
var a = 1 <- defined integer
var a = '' < defined "empty" string
```

Comment: Loosely coupled? You might have to elaborate what you mean by that. I don't think it means what you think it means.

Comment: js variables are only typed when assigned to a type. js allows you to change the type. making the typing loosely coupled.

Comment: Isn't that dynamic typing?

Comment: Yeah, I still don't see how how it's loosely coupled. I could see it being called dynamic typed or loosely typed. You'll have to explain why javascript is **loosely coupled**, because I don't understand.

Answer (score -2):

This is defining variable `question` which contains empty string. (as pointed out by dsfq in comments)

```
var question = '';
```

This is defining a object `question`  with `{}`

```
var question = {};
```

Comment: Come on. If you're going to answer a question on the most basic syntax, at least get at right.

Comment: @cookiemonster, is this okay now?

Comment: No, the *variable* contains something.

Comment: `which contains nothing`, it's not correct too. `''` contains empty string, it's not nothing, something, just empty string.

Comment: Then should I say it call empty string? I meant what's best language for this?

Comment: Why this answer is appearing as deleted answer?